# CakePhp: Avoid XSS attack keeping the ease of use of cake

Tags: php, security, cakephp, xss

One of the things I like with cakePhp, is that we can easily have a generated edited form which allows us to save.

E.g. in a controller:

```
function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Post->create();
            if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Post->User->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

The problem with that is that our fields are vulnerable to XSS (Cross site scripting). I'm aware of the "Sanitize::Clean" way, but I've a problem with that: it's mean that we have to do this on all fields before with save the object. And what if once we add one field? We should go on all our code to check that we sanitize it?? Is there any way to say "Sanitize this object before save it", without specifing any fields?

Thank you!

Comment: Also see [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/) article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at `beforeSave()` method for models

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1052/beforeSave

the data submitted is available in `$this->data[$this->alias]` array, so you could

```
foreach($this->data[$this->alias] as $k => $v) {
   $this->data[$this->alias][$k] = Sanitize::clean($v);
}
```

Usually you want to store whatever submitted by the user in the database and only sanitize it when you need to display it, that way you still preserve the original HTML content (if it indeed is intended to be an HTML input (for instance: blog post)).

If you want to Sanitize before displaying, you could do it using `afterFind()` so you don't have to call Sanitize everytime.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind

```
function afterFind($results, $primary) {
   $toSanitize = array('field1', 'field2', 'field4');
   if(!empty($results[0])) {
      foreach($results as $i => $res) {
         foreach($toSanitize as $ts) {
            if(!empty($res[$this->alias][$ts])) 
               $results[$i][$this->alias][$ts] = Sanitize::clean($res[$this->alias][$ts]);
            }
         }
      }
   } else {

     foreach($toSanitize as $ts) {
        if(!empty($results[$ts])) 
           $results[$ts] = Sanitize::clean($results[$ts]);
        }
     }
   }

   return $results;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I agree with your "store the original html" statement, but then, how to: escape html chars automatically without having to specify it on every display? Because otherwise, I'm sure that we will miss severals display because of the size of the project

Comment: If you have a consistent page and view design, you can make use of cakephp elements. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements, then whenever you need to display the fields, you just need to call `$this->element('your_element_which_sanitizes_input');`

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of elements, but we will have several different display of the same data type.

Comment: Then be my guest and sanitize it on `beforeSave()` :)

Comment: I tried, it seems to works, but I'm not fully satisfied: Every time I will have to edit this, we will see these html fields. If I want to sanitize on display, where shoud I do this? Because I think the best place to do it is in the view. But, I never saw an example with a Sanitize:Clean and the App::Import('Sanitize'); in a view

Answer (score 7):

As andreas correctly states, it is generally accepted best practice to store the original HTML and only sanitise on output (by storing the original input, it could help with tracking who posted the malicious content etc for example.).

To sanitize in a view, you should use the CakePHP convenience function `h($string)` which is a short cut for [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), which will render all attempts at XSS completely harmless.

edit - this wouldn't physically *remove* the XSS code, but just present it in a way that cannot harm your application.

`echo h('<script>alert("xss");</script>');`

would produce  `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;xss&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could sanitize in the [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1052/beforeSave#afterFind-1050) method of the Model. This would be called after a search, which you are probably doing before displaying your data.