# CakePHP : Prevent XSS attacks

Tags: php, cakephp, xss

I have developed an application in cakephp and what i found is the stored XSS attack in my application. To handle this attack i added the `Sanitizing::clean` in my application which converts the special characters into HTML code.

But when any string, which is sanitized, is used in a link `$this->Html->link` then that string gets encoded again due to default `escape=true` in cakephp. &lt turns &amp:lt which results in &lt instead of just <

Possible solution is to add the `escape=false` in `$this->Html->link` but i have created the application so there are too many places where `html->link` exists so it won't be efficient to go and change everywhere.

Please help if there is any other solution exist??

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Don't use the Sanitize class. Simply use `h()` instead. See [cakephp-security](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/)

Comment: i used h() also...still the same thing is happening. The special characters are getting encoded again when that encoded text is used in $this->Html->link due to default behaviour of escape = true..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786789/cakephp-avoid-xss-attack-keeping-the-ease-of-use-of-cake  Many seem to agree that it's preferable to store the unclean data, then make sure you never, ever display it. The default escape setting on the Html Helper would then take care of cross site scripting problems on your links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom helper like `MyHtmlHelper` which extends `HtmlHelper` and override the `link()` method.

In your controller include the using the aliasing feature like `public $helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtmlHelper'));` so you that  `$this->Html` in view will use your custom helper's instance and you won't have to make any changes in view files.